# How can I configure the Java GC Overhead Limit?

Tags: java, configuration, garbage-collection, jvm-arguments

Can the GC Overhead Limit be tuned rather than just enabled or disabled?

The Java GC Overhead Limit, whereby Java throws an OutOfMemoryError when it is doing "too much" garbage collection is great.  It's particularly nice in conjunction with HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, because it gives you a nice heapdump when your app is doing too much GC to be usable.

But I find it's just a bit slow to kick in, leading to a bunch of downtime when

I know that it can be turned on and off using -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit, but that's the opposite of what I want.  I want to tune the limit so that the OutOfMemoryError is thrown *sooner*.

I've searched http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html etc. to no avail.

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom) might help

Comment: Almost 3 years later, I asked the same question, but I got better answers (must be my face): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385050/how-can-i-oom-sooner-in-excessive-gc