# How can I OOM sooner in excessive GC?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

Occasionally my JVM runs out of memory, but rather then OOMing which I can recover from (or heapDumpOnOOM and debug) it tends to thrash in GC for hours before throwing out of memory. 
This is essentially the same as the (unanswered) question: [How can I configure the Java GC Overhead Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600720/how-can-i-configure-the-java-gc-overhead-limit) 
But I suspect the answer is you can't tune the 98%/2% thresholds, so I'm asking of any way to achieve similar effect. notice excessive GC, and preferably cause OOM, or kill the JVM or such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's [GC ergonomics guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) covers options for both thresholds.  `GCTimeLimit` and `GCHeapFreeLimit`. Lowering the former and increasing the latter should result in OOMs occuring sooner.